# How can I update a variable when the value goes through more than one function in C?

Tags: c, reference

I am trying to update a variable using two different functions. I wrote a little C program to demonstrate:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void updateHelper(int *x, int y) {
    *x = y;
}

void update(int x, int y) {
    updateHelper(&x, y);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int num = 0;
    update(num, 1);
    printf("%d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is this printing a 0 and not a 1? I can't wrap my head around this. The function that is actually updating the value is indeed passed a reference of the variable(!?). Can someone explain why this happens?

The arguments of update() can not be pointers. Are there any possible work-arounds for this?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the return type of `update`?

Comment: No. In my actual problem I am trying to update a data structure. And the interface would declare the function as void update(int, int) in this example. 
Is there really no way to do this?

Comment: Hmmm, I think your simplification/obfuscation made it harder to understand the problem, or to suggest valid alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys! I will think about other alternatives how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't updating the original variable. You're updating the *copy* of that variable that was passed to your `update` function. If you want to update the original variable, change `update` to take it's parameter as a pointer:

```
void update(int* x, int y) {
    updateHelper(x, y);
}
```

and in main, pass the address:

```
update(&num, 1);
```

Edit: since you stated the arguments to update cannot be pointers, you will need to either have `update` return the new variable, or use a global variable, or ... In C, the only way to modify a reference to a variable in a function is by using pointers.

Comment: Thank you. You made everything clear. I think I have some stuff to redesign.

Answer (score 0):

`x` in the call to `update` is just a local variable that happens to start with the same value as `num` in `main`. Therefore, even though *its* value is changed via the call to `updateHelper`, this has no effect on the value of `num`. That is, only the value of `num`, not it address, was passed to `update`, so nothing that happens subsequently during the call to `update` has any bearing on the value of `num`.

Answer (score 0):

```
update(int x,..)
```

int x here is a argument by value. ie a copy (new address created) of num is created and the value is copied.

try instead:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void updateHelper(int *x, int y) {
    *x = y;
}

void update(int *x, int y) {
    updateHelper(x, y);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int num = 0;
    update(&num, 1);
    printf("%d\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP specifically stated that `The arguments of update() can not be pointers`.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial call to the `update` function is a normal call-by-value, which means that `int num` gets copied, not referenced. Thus, when you later call `updateHelper` with a reference to the parameter `x`, all that gets modified is the copied value of num, local to the `update` function.

So, your call stack ends up looking like this (read from bottom to top):

```
main()
|               num: 0
|
update()                 < But `update's` x is a copy, does not point to anything
|               x: 1 .
|                     \
updateHelper()         | < Points to `update's` x
|                     /
|              *x: 1 ^
```

If your `update` function's interface can't take a pointer, then the only other options it has is to either return the modified value (which will also require a change to the interface), or to use a (possibly static) global variable.